# Cannot transfer file to cgi-bin folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xampp, cgi-bin

I have cgi-bin folder which is from windows OS and pasted in Linux desktop but i cannot paste the same folder in opt/lamp/cgi-bin folder.

Please also see picture. 
[image]

The directory is in **Filesystem**. Any idea how to do so?

Comment: Sounds like you try to copy or move a folder by means of a graphical file manager? in that case most likely you simply do not have permission to do so in the target location. But that is just a guess, since your question is extremely vague. Check the file permissions on your tar get location and compare it to the user account you are working under.

Comment: how shell i get permission for FIlesystem. bcz i by using graphical user inter face went though Home Folder then selected Filesystem/lamp/opt/cgi-bin.

Comment: well like u said permission the whole folder does neeed permission to access even htdoc which i cannot place file.

Comment: You should read a basic getting started tutorial about Linux systems. You need to learn and understand how linux (or better unixoid) file system permissions work. How you can use and alter them. That stuff simply works different to what you are used to from MS-Windows. And there is a reason _why_ it is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this command line :

```
sudo cp -r ~/Desktop/cgi-bin /opt/lamp/cgi-bin
```

Comment: giving me "cp: cannot create directory `opt/lamp/cgi-bin': No such file or directory"

Comment: sorry typo error it is /opt/lamp/cgi-bin instead of opt/lamp/cgi-bin. Try again please.

Comment: its sudo cp -r ~/Desktop/cgi-bin /opt/lampp/cgi-bin

Comment: 1 thing more its has separtely created folder but i want only files to be copied there. What command for tha?

Comment: try with this : sudo cp ~/Desktop/cgi-bin/* /opt/lamp/cgi-bin